# Do I not have to pay state tax on capital gains on my stock sales?

Tags: united-states, capital-gains-tax, state-income-tax, new-jersey

I live in NJ and for tax purposes, I am a full year resident of NJ. In the NJwebfile site, I cannot find any option to report capital gains on my stock sales. Also in the instructions, I could not find anything relevant either. Does this mean, I don't have to report gains on my stock sales?

Comment: Yes, you need to pay taxes on all your income in the state in which you are a resident https://www.state.nj.us/treasury/taxation/njit9.shtml

Comment: Hmm, I found that link too, but it doesn't specify where exactly I need to report capital gains from stock transactions. Is "Net Gains or Income From Disposition of Property in the New Jersey Income Tax return" worksheet the place where I need to report my stock related capital gains?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [NJ-1040 instructions](https://www.state.nj.us/treasury/taxation/pdf/current/1040i.pdf):

> **Line 19 – Net Gains or Income From Disposition of Property**
>
> Complete Schedule NJ-DOP and enter the amount from Line 4. If the amount on
>   Line 4 is a loss, make no entry on Line 19.
>
> **Do not include** on Schedule
>   NJ-DOP:
>
> - Gains/losses from the disposition of property owned by a sole
>     proprietorship, a partnership, or an S corporation. Report on Schedule
>     NJ-BUS-1.
> - Gains/losses from the disposition of property owned by an
>     estate or trust (other than a grantor trust). Report on Line 26

Then directly below that part they discuss how to complete the [Schedule NJ-DOP](https://www.state.nj.us/treasury/taxation/pdf/current/schedulenjdop.pdf):

> **Line 1: List of Transactions**
>
> List any New Jersey taxable transaction(s) as reported on your federal Schedule D, indicating the gain or loss for each transaction
>   in Column f. In listing the gain or loss on disposition of rental
>   property, you must take into consideration the New Jersey adjustment
>   from Worksheet GIT-DEP, Part 1, line 6.

it looks like most of the information for this schedule NJ-DOP is from Federal schedule D.